# How to set resolution parameter for Cluster Info Map in R-igraph?

Tags: r, igraph

I am applying the Cluster Info Map algorithm for community detection for a set of large networks. I can achieve high modularity scores of around 0.6 however this comes with getting very high numbers of communities (18-24) which complicates my final analysis. Ideally, I would like to work with 10-15 communities. Is there any way to adjust how many communities are ultimately detected in my network using a resolution/modularity parameter or otherwise?

I've seen similar questions for Louvain and other algorithms, but nothing specifically on the Cluster Info Map algorithm. Nor does the official documentation for the standard function show anything about a resolution parameter. https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/igraph/html/cluster_infomap.html

I'm wondering if there is some other workaround available? Example of my code below for a weighted, directed network.

```
ci <-cluster_infomap(network, 
                     e.weights = E(network)$weight,
                     nb.trial=50)
```

Answer (score 1):

The Infomap implementation included in igraph does not have any parameters that allow controlling the number of communities or the resolution. igraph's `cluster_infomap` is based on the [old Infomap package](https://www.mapequation.org/code_old.html).

[The new Python Infomap package](https://mapequation.github.io/infomap/python/) supports several features which you might find helpful, including hierarchical partitioning.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into this.

Is there any analogue package in R?